# Standardized Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

Let's assume I have a test subject of $n$ students. If I already know the mean and sd values how can I find how many students have a value greater than $y$?
For reference let mean = $10$, sd = $5$,  $n = 1.000.000$  and $y= 13$.

The way I've approached this question so far is this:
\begin{eqnarray}
P(X > 13) = 1 - P\left(Z < \frac{13 - 10}{5}\right).  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (1)
\end{eqnarray}
Thus I got the probability. My real problem is how to use the number of students given to get the result. Should I just multiply the result I got from (1) with $n$ or is there another way of solving this?

Comment: Did you mean $\frac{13-10}{5}$?

Comment: yeah i did mean that

Comment: If $x$ is $13$, it is not a random variable.

Comment: you are right, my mistake

Comment: If you have 100 students each with a 40% chance of getting an A, on average how many of the 100 do you expect to get A's?

Comment: @Glen_b, the *on average* part is an important addition. Since we could not answer *"how many do you expect to get A's"* with a single number.

Answer (score 1):

You got the probability of each student having a value greater than 13 - assuming that the values follow a normal distribution. If you are asked about how many students you expect with a larger value, you just have to multiply that probability by n.

However, please keep in mind that since each student can have a value larger or smaller than 13 with the given probability, the number of students over 13 is a random variable, distributed as a binomial variable with number of trials equal to n and the probability you got from (1).